# Creating a multiple layer DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I am working on a project where I have a programmatically created a gridview with (n,m) size. The table content (entered manually not from a data source) is like the following: columns (Week 1, Week 2..etc) and each week has row entries like total working hours, cost, efficiency, and so on.

My idea is when to click on the first cell of each week column using the Datagridview1.CellDoubleClick(..) event the table will view the days on that week, so the table columns headers will become (Monday, Tuesday,... etc) and the data in the table will change.

Until this point it is achievable. I also created a cell in the 'days' table with value "back" that should switch back to the weekly table. But I couldn't figure out how to toggle between them. What I did up until now is a one-way switch.

Example:

```
private TabItem Table(){

Table = new forms.DataGridView();
Table.BackgroundColor =drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 34, 116, 172); 
//..Here table entries are made for weekly data view

Table .CellDoubleClick += delegate (object sender, forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs args)
               {
                var senderGrid = (forms.DataGridView)sender;

              //if a cell in a certain week in clicked it should switch to weekly view

              if (senderGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex == 0 && 
                        senderGrid.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.HeaderText.Contains("Week"))
                   {
                   //Clear Old table and redraw new Columns and rows with (daily) data inputs

                   }
                    
                   //*****Help Needed Here***// I want to go back to weekly view when a cell with 
                    //value "back" is double pressed

                    if (senderGrid.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() == ("<- Back"))
                   {
                   ***//Go back to weekly view***
                   }
                   };
}
}
```

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: The best way is to have the source data in a DataTable and two additional tables for Weekly Data and Daily Data.  Then simply make the DGV DataSource either the Weekly Table or the Daily Table.

Comment: @jdweng I hope you are doing well! Thank you for answering again on my questions. I thought about it but still, didn't figure it out. I will do more research on this method. Thanks alot.

Comment: @jdweng Tried that and did work like a charm! Thank you. This question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @jdweng .

By having multiple Data sources it can be easily manipulated by the datagridview events.